# SVG overlay / gridlines over iframe

Tags: css, svg

I want to add gridlines over a iframe while still keeping the iframe accessible. The lines would be used to indicate different screen sizes and should not interfere with any interaction behind them.

I have been able to show some lines but they do not stretch the full iframe height and the items below them are not accessible.

```
 <div id="wrapper">
      <svg class="gridlines">
           <line x1="200" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200" class="leftLine" style="stroke: rgb(255, 0, 0); stroke-width: 2px;"></line>
           <line x1="400" y1="0" x2="400" y2="400" class="rightLine" style="stroke: rgb(255, 0, 0); stroke-width: 2px;"></line></svg>
      </div>
      <iframe src='...'></iframe>
 </div>

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.gridlines {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.gridlines lines {
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 2;
}
.gridlines .leftline {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your SVG on top of your iframe, and set `pointer-events: none`

```css
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
}  

.gridlines {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}

iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <iframe src="."></iframe>

  <svg class="gridlines">
    <line x1="200" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200" class="leftLine" style="stroke: rgb(255, 0, 0); stroke-width: 2px;"></line>
    <line x1="400" y1="0" x2="400" y2="400" class="rightLine" style="stroke: rgb(255, 0, 0); stroke-width: 2px;"></line>
  </svg>

</div>
```